# SQL INSERT and relations

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Использую MySql. Есть две таблицы со связью многие ко многим. В общем прилагаю скрин...[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как правильно составить запрос для добавления данных сразу в две таблицы,чтобы строки с этими данными были связаны? Потому что мой вариант таблицу инфо заполнил,но при этом ид_в в ней ссылался на не созданную запись в таблице визитеров,при том что оба запроса отработали(делал двумя запросами СЕТ,через точку с запятой) 
Как правильно выбрать селектом все данные из обеих таблиц? Пробовал джоином, не тру...

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, лень вникать в подробности вашей бд, но сразу же бросается в глаза очевидная ошибка - у вас неправильно задано отношение "многие-ко многим". Двумя таблицами оно не реализуется. Для его корректной реализации необходима промежуточная таблица, в которой будут храниться отношения между элементами первой и второй таблиц.

Comment: да,точно,вы правы,спасибо! Надеюсь поможет